# Does [history.push] in useEffect dependency array cause rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can't find documentation about this anywhere. Will this cause the `useEffect` to EVER run again? I don't want it to fetch twice, that would cause some issues in my code.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const myComponent = () => {
  const { push } = useHistory();

  useEffect( () => {
    console.log(" THIS SHOULD RUN ONLY ONCE ");
    fetch(/*something*/)
      .then( () => push('/login') );
  }, [push]);
  

  return <p> Hello, World! </p>
}
```

From testing, it doesn't ever run twice. Is there a case that it would?

For the sake of the question, assume that the component's parent is rerendering often, and so this component is as well. The `push` function doesn't seem to change between renders - will it ever?

Answer (score 4):

Ciao, the way you write `useEffect` is absolutely right. And `useEffect` will be not triggered an infinite number of time. As you said, `push` function doesn't change between renders.

So you correctly added `push` on `useEffect` deps list in order to be called after `fetch` request. I can't see any error in your code.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I'm wondering if it will ever change though - I know it doesn't cause a loop, since using the `push` function doesn't change the `push` function, but i'd like _never_ to run the effect again, if I can help it

Comment: So you mean that you want to run code inside useEffect just first time and never again correct?

Comment: That's right, I'm worried it will run again at some point